# How do I take a screenshot on a Raspberry Pi running Debian Squeeze and LXDE?

Tags: debian-based, raspberry-pi

Noob question...

But shutter not installed, print screen doesn't appear to work, screen grab not installed etc.

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to find the comedy+ button on this site.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7423/how-to-printscreen-on-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved with ImageMagick. Install by running the command

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

To grab all desktop just type

```
import -window root screen.png
```

Or you can do it with a delay of 5 seconds

```
sleep 5; import -window root screen.png
```

Comment: What if you do not have XWindow running, and want to grab the screen of a console based app?

Answer (score 6):

For a lighter weight screenshot tool, use scrot

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
```

To take a screenshot, at the terminal, just type

```
scrot
```

To take a screenshot after, say, 5 seconds

```
scrot -d 5
```